# Problem in installing Xcode on MacBook Air 2017 with macos Mojave version 10.14.5

Tags: applications, install, xcode, mac-appstore

I am trying to download Xcode from the mac app store but it fails again and again. I am using my mobile hotspot for internet. It has a daily data limit of 2.5 GB but Xcode is of 6.1 GB. Once I put Xcode on download from the app store and it processed till 2 GB and then it failed saying slow internet connection. I also tried to pause the download in between but on resuming, it restarts from the starting. I also tried to download it from Apple's website but that also didn't work. Please help with this issue.

Comment: https://dev.to/jahirfiquitiva/direct-download-any-xcode-385o See if this helps. Also, Please add in the question, what didn't work in Apple's website? You can use IIT-K Wi-Fi to install it though. That's how I did it. Now I am using VSCode, due to space crunch.

Comment: Use a better internet connection which does not have a data limit smaller than the size of the package you are trying to download...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download bittorrent version of Xcode but there's always a risk of downloading files from unknown source and you may not be able to find the latest version, as I could only find Xcode 9.

Side note: In the past, I would've recommended a tool called [ADCDownload](https://github.com/MagLoft/adcdownload), which allows you to resume downloads from Apple Developer website. But it hasn't been updated in awhile, and likely  no longer working.